# Enigmatic GET request from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I am seeing a strange thing, when I run the server for my Rails app. This is the log:

```
Jatins-MacBook-Pro: silverSpoon$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/app/update-progress" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-19 15:04:56 +0530
Connecting to database specified by database.yml

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/app/update-progress"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'

Rendered /Users/silverSpoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@fbTracker/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.3ms)
```

And, then the request is made repeatedly. Please guide me to find the cause of such behaviour and how to fix this.

The output of `rake:routes` is:

```
bash-3.2$ rake routes
    trackers        /trackers(.:format)                tracker#index
        root        /                                  home#index
       users POST   /users(.:format)                   users#create
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               users#show
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)               users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)               users#destroy
                    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
auth_failure        /auth/failure(.:format)            :controller#:action
     signout        /signout(.:format)                 sessions#destroy
                    /online/:id(.:format)              users#function
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: have you try test with command `rake`? what is error message?

Comment: @hendrathings: I didn't understand what you were asking about "trying test with command rake"? Could you please elaborate...

Comment: have you tried to use an anonymous session with your Explorer?or check from another computer? Maybe there's an extension doing the enigmatic requests, even a virus

Comment: See the error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/app/update-progress"`, try create unit test for your app and track with command `rake` or `rake test:..` the error mean there is no have match route

Comment: @AlterLagos: I tried with an anonymous session, but the requests are still repeatedly happening.

Comment: @AlterLagos: Also, I tried from another computer using my IP, but still the same result.

Comment: @hendrathings: I understand what the error means. I want to know what's the logic behind making a unit test to figure out the issue behind this.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript, or gems that may insert JavaScript into your asset pipeline? My guess is that this is an ajax request to get percentage data used to update a progress bar. The request is made repeatedly because in order to provide timely feedback, the bar needs to update at least once a second or so.

Comment: @ZachKemp: You're right man. I was playing around with progress bar and that was the cause for the spurious and enigmatic requests.
Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app doesn't have a route to `/app/update_progress`. So it is one of the below which is calling that in your app:

1. Javascript code in your app (do you use [this Bootstrap Progressbar](http://elfga.com/blog/2012/10/03/bootstrap-progress-bar-update-jqueryajax/) by any chance?)

   To test whether this is the source of the problem - Open Chrome Developer Tools and go to the [Network panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network). Now open your application `localhost:3000`. If you see consistent calls in this Network tab to `localhost:3000/app/update_progress`, then it means your application is firing these requests from Javascript. Now you need to search your codebase to find out where that javascript code is. It may be inside some jquery extension that you have downloaded too. You can [create a breakpoint in Javascript whenever an Ajax request is made](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-xhr) to `/app/update_progress`.
2. A chrome/firefox extension

   To rule this out, Open Chrome/Firefox in Incognito mode (which usually disables all extensions), and open your application. If you still see hits to `/app/update_progress` then most likely its not an extension which is causing problems.
3. Some external gem that you're using

   If the above two don't materialize, then post your Gemfile.

Comment: You nailed it man. Yes, I was playing around Bootstrap Progress bar. Most definitely, that would be the reason for such behavior

Comment: @JatinGanhotra, can you please check if this worked, and let me know if any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is.

When you start your server, it receives a request for

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/app/update-progress
```

but there is no route for this request (Rails doesn't know what to do with that request) so you get that error.

To handle that request add a route:

```rb
match '/app/update-progress/' => 'some#action'
```

To find out more about the request, examine the `request` object from inside the action.